# Setting common instance variables to all classes using decorator or metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

I have a scenario where class A is initialized with parameters id,name,email,ticket. Then class B is initialized inside class A's method and the same parameters are required to be passed along and so on and so forth. Can these common attributes be set using a decorator or metaclass during class declaration.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, id, name,  email, ticket):
       self.id = id
       self.name=name
       self.email=email
       self.ticket=ticket

  def __somefunc(self):
       # do something
        b = B(self.id, self.name, self.email, self.ticket)
        b.__dosomething()
```

Similarly...class C and so on..
I am finding it bit inappropriate sending all these repeated parameters to all the subsequent classes.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just less typing?

Comment: Maybe have A hold onto a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and just pass that around?

Comment: Is there any further difference between `A.__init__` and `B.__init__`? A class method `B.from_A` might also be appropriate, to encapsulate the process of creating an instance of `B` given an instance of `A`.

Comment: `Can these common attributes be set using ...`? *set* on the instance created in `__somefunc` only  or on `A` also?

Comment: Why did you think of using a a decorator or meta class? You really haven't explained your motivation - what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to reduce the number of characters typed  (appearing in the code), make a dictionary of those values and *instantiate* the other classes with it.

```
Class A:
  def __init__(self, id, name,  email, ticket):
       self.id = id
       self.name=name
       self.email=email
       self.ticket=ticket
       self.params = {'id':id, 'name':name,  'email':email, 'ticket':ticket} 

  def __somefunc(self):
       # do something
        b = B(**self.params)
        b.__dosomething()
```

---

`Can these common attributes be set using a decorator or metaclass during class declaration.`?
Yes and probably.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class decorator to "remember" the parameters as part of the instance, so you would be able to access them using `self.args` and `self.kwargs`:

```py
import functools


def remember_params(cls):
    @functools.wraps(cls)
    def instance_creator(*args, **kwargs):
        obj = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        obj.args = args
        obj.kwargs = kwargs
        return obj
    return instance_creator


class B:
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)


@remember_params
class C:
    def __init__(self, id, name, email, ticket):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.ticket = ticket

    def something(self):
        b = B(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```